# Compute the angle between a line and a plane if the line forms the angles of 45 degrees and 60 degrees with two perpendicular lines lying in the plane

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

Compute the angle between a line and a plane if the line forms the angles of 45 degrees and 60 degrees with two perpendicular lines lying in the plane.

I have no idea how to solve this exercise. I thought that since the line is crossing two lines which are lying in the plane, then the line has two point lying in the plane, and then the whole line lies in the plane and the angle between it and the plane is 0 degrees.

Comment: Have a look at this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine

Comment: This exercise is given in textbook for high school students, we haven't learn any analytic geometry. I guess there must be simple way.

Comment: Think of a right angled pyramid which you know the angels that two sides form with the base. Than you need to compute the angel of the line that is the intersection of these two sides.

Comment: Any hint how the line intersects the sides?

Comment: Also I can understand how a line will have two points with a plane and wouldn't lie in this plane. This is opposition to the Postulate 5 by Euclid
 If two points lie in a plane, then the line joining them lies in that plane.

Comment: Possible hint: if you have two perpendicular lines in a plane, you can regard them as the x and y axes of a Cartesian coordinate system.

Comment: If you can't use analytic geometry, what kind of math can you use? Trigonometry? Just geometry?

Comment: Both trigonometry and geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this picture helping you with deriving the solution? If not, will calculate it for you.

[image]